# TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I have been using an API in JavaScript.
**What the API does -** We send the URL to the API and it sends back the shorten URL and response as an object.

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
      "code": "KCveN",
      "short_link": "shrtco.de/KCveN",
      "full_short_link": "https://shrtco.de/KCveN",
      "short_link2": "9qr.de/KCveN",
      "full_short_link2": "https://9qr.de/KCveN",
      "share_link": "shrtco.de/share/KCveN",
      "full_share_link": "https://shrtco.de/share/KCveN",
      "original_link": "http://example.org/very/long/link.html"
  }
}
```

But in my case, it shows TypeError.
It shows error above the `catch` in console.

I am also unable to access the data sent back.

**MY CODE**

```
import React , {useState} from 'react'


function Content() {
    const [url, setState] = useState("")

     function shorten() {
        var api = new URL("https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten"),
            params = { url }
        Object.keys(params).forEach(key => api.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
        fetch(api , {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            
        }).then(res => {
               
                console.log(res)
                return res.json()
            
        })
        .then(data => {
            
            console.log(data)
            return data
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      
    }
     

    return (
        
        <>
            <Section>
                <Started>More than just shorter links<Para>Build your brand's recogination and get detailed
                insights on how your links are performing</Para>
                <Button>Get Started</Button></Started>
                
                <Image src={image}></Image>
            </Section>
            <BackgroundColour>
            <FormSection>
                <InputSection>
                    <Input value={url} onChange = {(e) => setState(e.target.value)} type="url" placeholder= "Shorten a link here..."></Input>
                    <ButtonLink onClick = {shorten}>Shorten it!</ButtonLink>

                </InputSection>

            </FormSection>
            </BackgroundColour>

        </>
    )
}

export default Content
```

The problem is that I was unable to access the contents from the response that I received. I am able to see it as a response in the console (*XHR request*) as well as in the network tab. But the raw response is a JSON. I tried accessing it with `res.body` and `res.result` but both are `null` and `undefined` respectively. when I try to see it after the `.json()` call it shows the error in the heading.

Comment: is some section of your code missing? please create a minimal reproducible problem.

Comment: This is the main part and rest is ReactJS.